# JQuery, перехватить отправку формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Форма:

```
<form action="/send" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
...
<button class="modal_vacancy__btn btn btn_send">
Sent
</button>
```

Нужно проверить значения в некоторых полях и если проверка прошла, то отправить форму средствами JQuery, если нет - отправку запретить.

пробовал так `$('#form').submit(function(event) {event.preventDefault();}` и так `$('#student_form').on('submit', function(e) {e.preventDefault();}` не перехватывает.

Comment: `$('#form').on('submit', function({if(проверка) {/*если true*/} else {/* если false */ return false; // для отмены отправки} }):`

Comment: Спасибо, вроде получилось

Answer (score 0):

Решение с ранним return:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
    if(!проверка) return false; // возвращаем false сразу же, если проверка не пройдена
        
    /* код, если проверка пройдена */
});
```